# how to preview the selected image upload React js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Have created a button called image upload, need to view the selected image when selected

```
     <GridItem xs={6}>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            className={classes.input}
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            id="raised-button-file"
            multiple
            type="file"
          />
          <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
            <Button
              variant="raised"
              component="span"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Upload Image
            </Button>
          </label>
        </FormControl>
      </GridItem>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set the file object URL in the state during the `onChange` and use it in an `img` tag like this,

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(undefined);

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
  }
```

use this `handleChange` method in `input` `onChange` event,

```
<GridItem xs={6}>
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
  <input
    accept="image/*"
    className={classes.input}
    style={{ display: 'none' }}
    id="raised-button-file"
    multiple
    type="file"
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  {/* preview of file */}
  { file && <img src={this.state.file}/>}
  <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
    <Button
      variant="raised"
      component="span"
      className={classes.button}
    >
      Upload Image
    </Button>
  </label>
</FormControl>
</GridItem>
```

also if you want to allow the user to crop the image selected there is this library [react-image-crop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop). I use it and it works pretty good for me.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, getting an error 'handleChange' is not defined

Comment: have you added the code for `handleChange` to your component class?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, i'm using react hooks so this.setState won't be used

Answer (score 1):

### before select

[image: before select]

### select image

[image]

**Typescript**

```js
import { Grid, IconButton, makeStyles, Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core'
import { PhotoCamera, Publish } from "@material-ui/icons"
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { IRequestState } from '../../assets/interfaces'

const FILE = 'ImageUpload.tsx'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  }, right: {
    float: "right"
  }, w100: {
    width: "100%"
  }, input: {
    display: "none",
  },
  faceImage: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.light,
  }, success: {
    color: theme.palette.success.main
  }
}))

interface IImageUploadProps {
  Submit(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void
}

type IImageUploadState = IRequestState & {
  imageFile?: any
}

export default function ImageUpload(props: IImageUploadProps) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const initState: IImageUploadState = { inited: false, requesting: false }

  const [values, setState] = useState<IImageUploadState>(initState)

  const handleCapture = ({ target }: any) => {
    if (target && target.files && target.files.length)
      setState({ ...values, imageFile: target.files[0] })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="space-evenly"
        alignItems="center"
        spacing={2}
      >
        <Grid item sm={6} md={3}>
          <Grid
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center"
            container
          >
            <Grid item>
              <input
                accept="image/jpeg"
                className={classes.input}
                id="faceImage"
                type="file"
                onChange={handleCapture}
              />
              <Tooltip title="select image">
                <label htmlFor="faceImage">
                  <IconButton
                    className={classes.faceImage}
                    color="primary"
                    aria-label="upload picture"
                    component="span"
                  >
                    <PhotoCamera fontSize="large" />
                  </IconButton>
                </label>
              </Tooltip>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={6} md={3}>
          <img className={classes.w100} hidden={!values.imageFile} src={values.imageFile && URL.createObjectURL(values.imageFile)} alt="Logo" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={6} md={3}>
          <Grid
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center"
            container
          >
            <Grid item>
              <Tooltip title="upload image">
                <IconButton
                  className={classes.success}
                  aria-label="upload"
                  onClick={props.Submit}
                  edge="end"
                  disabled={!values.imageFile}
                >
                  <Publish />
                </IconButton>
              </Tooltip>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}
```